# PowerShell script called from within the Jenkins PowerShell build step hangs indefinitely

Tags: powershell, jenkins, freeze

I have a Jenkins (1.493) project that uses the Jenkins PowerShell build step to execute a PowerShell script. Inside that script I want to invoke another script that is stored inside a file. I have now reduced it to the following:

Script inside Jenkins PowerShell build step:
`& "\\stemmer.local\sidevelopment\cvdev\devbase\jenkins\PowerShell\Test.ps1"`

Content of Test.ps1:
`write-host 'Hello world!'`

Whenever this Jenkins project executes, the PowerShell build step hangs indefinitely.

Things I have tried/verified so far:

- Adding some output before the invocation of `Test.ps1` shows me that the Jenkins PowerShell script is being execute normally up to the point where `Test.ps1` is called.
- The file `Test.ps1` exists and is reachable from the build slave that executes the script. If I alter the file's name, I get the expected error message from PowerShell...
- Exchanging the " for ' in the 1st script does not change anything. Also, using dot-sourcing rather than `&` does not help.
- The file `Test.ps1` can be executed properly from the powershell itself using the same command line that is being used in the Jenkins PowerShell script.
- The execution policy for PowerShell has been set to `unrestricted` on my development host as well as on the Jenkins build slave.
- I've tried replacing the PowerShell build step with a Windows batch command build step that looks like this:
  `powershell.exe -InputFormat None -File "\\stemmer.local\sidevelopment\cvdev\devbase\jenkins\PowerShell\Test.ps1"`
  and played around a little with the parameters of powershell.exe, but the results were - in those cases that were syntactically and otherwise correct as far as I can tell - always the same.

I only found few references to problems that sounded similar, but none of the approaches mentioned elsewhere did help me fix this. I am absolutely puzzled, and wondering whether someone encountered this issue before (and maybe even got a scenario like the one I have in mind running).

Thanks a lot for any input!

```
Volker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to set execution policy to bypass ?

Copy the script file locally, then invoke it from within the `Jenkins` `PowerShell` plugin - that way it works as expected.

Comment: I did (admittedly only after you mentioned it), but it doesn't change the behavior. Thanks for the quick reply, though!

Comment: I never used jenkins so canot help you more beyond basics : have you try to move the script to the localcomputer, are there any log files etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Copying the script locally actually does the trick - if I e.g. execute `& "C:\Test.ps1"` in my script (and the file is there) it runs properly, so the problem is only with scripts that run from the network share. The log files from Jenkins yield nothing (basically Jenkins captures the output of the invoked scripts, but nothing seems to be starting - hence no log...). On the build machines jenkins runs as a service - which might also contribute to the problem...

Comment: verify the account running jenkins, maybe it's not allowed on the network share

Comment: I think with your last questions you actually brought me close enough to a solution: I can copy the scripts to a local folder prior to executing them, that way I can achieve what I initially planned. I'll give it a few tries, then probably mark your reply as the answer. Thanks a lot Kayasax!

Comment: It's not the network share access - copying the script from there works. But it definitely must have to do with rights - probably some configuration/policy I am missing here. But copying locally is just one additional line, so I am happy. Thanks a lot for your help!